# Error loading office add-in in excel(16.9) for mac when user is logged in

Tags: office-js, office-addins, excel-addins

We have developed an office add-in for excel using office.js and we are facing a strange issue which is impacting our business users.

When user is logged in to his office account in excel, add-in does not load and shows error loading error and when user logs out from office account, it loads.
we updated the excel to latest and even re-installed it but didn't seem to help.

Is there any cache/data which are stored in office account that is affecting  the add-in?

-Thanks

Comment: Can you show what the error message is?